# speech to text watson: time out issue

Tags: java, android, speech-to-text, watson

I am having some issues with Watson speech to text, I get a time out error when I try to send a file.

error below:

code below:

```
  final InputStream inputStream = FileUtils.openInputStream(files[spnRecordingList.getSelectedItemPosition()]);
        final FileInputStream input2 = new FileInputStream(files[spnRecordingList.getSelectedItemPosition()]);
        Log.i("transcribe", "input2 created");
        recognizeOptions = new RecognizeOptions.Builder().contentType(HttpMediaType.AUDIO_WAV).maxAlternatives(3).interimResults(true).build();
        Log.i("transcribe", "options");

        final BaseRecognizeCallback callback = new BaseRecognizeCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onTranscription(SpeechResults speechResults) {
                Log.i("callback", "on transcription");
                txtbox.setText(speechResults.toString());
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e){
                Log.i("callback", "on error");
                Log.i("callback", e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDisconnected() {
                Log.i("callback", "on disconnected");
            }
        };

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    service.recognizeUsingWebSocket(inputStream, recognizeOptions, callback);
                    //   service.recognize(files[spnRecordingList.getSelectedItemPosition()], recognizeOptions);
                    Log.i("transcribe", "inside the try statement");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("try", e.toString());

                }
            }
        }).start();
}
```

stack trace

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
okio.Okio$4.newTimeoutException(Okio.java:230)
okio.AsyncTimeout.exit(AsyncTimeout.java:285)
okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:241)
okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:345)
okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:217)
okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:211)
okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http1Codec.java:189)
okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:75)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:120)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:185)
okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:135)
okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_read(Native Method)
    com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:789)
    okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:139)
    okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:237)
    ... 23 more
```

I have looked online and asked IBM's dev community and haven't gotten anywhere on why im getting the issue considering I followed the example IBM gives here [github](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/android-sdk/blob/master/example/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/developer_cloud/android/myapplication/MainActivity.java)

Comment: What logs do you get before the timeout & stack trace?

Comment: Hi Nathan, sadly I am having an issue with android studio 3.0 with dex and none of the fixes I have found are solving it so I cant give you a complete list but before the time out it logs   Log.i("transcribe", "inside the try statement"); and just general stuff like when I click the button.

Comment: Ok. I asked someone else to look at it, and they thought it was a threading thing that wasn't really related to watson. What happens if you comment out all of the watson stuff and just put in a couple of `sleep()` calls?

Comment: Hi @NathanFriedly Sorry for the delay, I just managed to get my dex issue to work. I went back over the API documentation and figured out my issue was I was attempting to use a session instead of being session-less so now I have it working and I am getting error 
    E/WatsonService: POST https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize/v1/recognize?max_alternatives=3, status: 404, error: No such child resource.
    E/try: com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.exception.NotFoundException: No such child resource.

Comment: I think that extra v1 shouldn't be there at the end, are you manually setting the URL?

Comment: @NathanFriedly ah Thank you, I was looking online and it was posted to use that one, i double checked my credentials and its now working. Thank you very much for the help.